# Event not being observed

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, configuration

Below I have pasted my observer and config as I currently have them.

`app/code/local/Skytiger/Redirection/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <models>
        <redirection>
            <class>Skytiger_Redirection_Model</class>
        </redirection>
    </models>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view>
                <observers>
                    <skytiger_redirection>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>skytiger_redirection/observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchCmsPageView</method>
                    </skytiger_redirection>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Skytiger/Redirection/Model/Observer.php`:

```
<?php
class Skytiger_Redirection_Model_Observer/* extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer*/
{
    public function controllerActionPredispatchCmsPageView(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** code here ... */

    }
}
```

When trying to hit the `/home` page (which should then be redirected to `/`), I get the following error:

> Warning: include(Mage/Skytiger/Redirection/Model/Observer.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /var/www/clean.magento.181/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Now, the error tells me that it's not looking for the correct file. It says it's looking for `Mage/Skytiger/Redirection/Model/Observer.php` instead of for `Skytiger/Redirection/Model/Observer.php`, which means that there is an error in my `config.xm` somewhere. Need some help finding that problem, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `<class>redirection/observer</class>` insetad of `<class>skytiger_redirection/observer</class>`

you are missing the `global` tag also models alwasy define in `<global>` tag

```
<global>
  <models>
        <redirection>
            <class>Skytiger_Redirection_Model</class>
        </redirection>
    </models>
</global>
```

your complete config.xml look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Skytiger_Redirection>
         <version>1.1.0</version>
        </Skytiger_Redirection>
     </modules>
   <global>
    <models>
        <redirection>
            <class>Skytiger_Redirection_Model</class>
        </redirection>
    </models>
   </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view>
                <observers>
                    <skytiger_redirection>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>redirection/observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchCmsPageView</method>
                    </skytiger_redirection>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the same error except that it no longer looks for skytiger at all: `Warning: include(Mage/Redirection/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/clean.magento.181/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93`

Comment: added the solution you were missing the `<global></global>` tag

Comment: Cue me slamming my head in a door for being an idiot... Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 4):

replace in `config.xml` this

```
<redirection>
    <class>Skytiger_Redirection_Model</class>
</redirection>
```

with

```
<skytiger_redirection>
    <class>Skytiger_Redirection_Model</class>
</skytiger_redirection>
```

and clear the cache.
And move the `<models>` section inside the `<global>` tag instead of `<config>`.

Comment: I don't cache when I develop, so that's not a problem. Isn't that node in the config just a unique name?

Comment: No. It's the alias of your models In other words it's the part before the slash in `Mage::getModel('something/here')`